# How would I take a boolean value as one of my function arguments, and what is the syntax?

Tags: python, boolean

So I'm designing a function for school that needs to take an argument (bool) that in this case would indicate if someone refused a BAC test (true/false)
I don't have much experience with bool values, so I'm just wondering what the syntax would be, based off my function. If false, I plan on printing 'fail' before all the other elif/if statements

```
def print_roadside_penalty(bac: int, in_num: int, sam_prov: bool):
  
    if ......
    
    elif bac < 50:
        print('no penalty')
    
elif bac >= 80:
        print (fail)
    
elif in_num == 1:
        print('Driving Prohibition Length: 3 days \nVehicle Impoundment Length: 3 days \nPenalties and Fees: $600')
    
elif in_num == 2:
        print('Driving Prohibition Length: 7 days \nVehicle Impoundment Length: 7 days \nPenalties and Fees: $780')
    
elif in_num == 3:
        print('Driving Prohibition Length: 30 days \nVehicle Impoundment Length: 30 days \nPenalties and Fees: $1430')
```

Comment: It's just a variable.  There's no special syntax.  You'll get either `True` or `False`, and you'll use it like any other variable.  `if sam_prov:`

Comment: All you need to do is **have** a boolean value; then you pass it *the same way you would pass anything else*. The possible values are `True` and `False` - they must have capitals. Or you can use any expression that gives you (*evaluates to*) such a result. Again, just like with any other type. Please try to follow a Python tutorial from start to finish and learn the fundamentals.

Comment: You just can't assume its boolean as true and false results come from [all sorts](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if not sam_prov:
    print("fail")
```

This is the same as

```
if sam_prov == False:
    print("fail")
```

But its better programming practice to not write == True or == False when evaluating booleans. When you want to know if a boolean is True, you can just say

```
if sam_prov:
```

rather than

```
if sam_prov == True:
```